# Adding second like clause in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I 'm trying to get lines from an sqlite database that contain a certain word in 'A1' column and another in 'A2' column. My code looks like this:

```
a = input("Please insert word")
b = input("Please insert second word")
  ....
c.execute("SELECT * FROM board WHERE A1 LIKE ?" ("%" + a + "%",), "AND A2 LIKE ?" ("%" + b + "%",))
```

I 'm getting a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable. I am pretty sure my syntax is wrong but i cannot figure out how the correct one should be. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [execute() method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) expects two parameters: a single SQL statement string, and a list containing the SQL parameters:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM board WHERE A1 LIKE ? AND A2 LIKE ?",
          ("%" + a + "%", "%" + b + "%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the last line. Should be something like this

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM board WHERE A1 LIKE ? % {} % AND A2 LIKE ? % {} %".format(a,b))
```

Comment: It gives me error sqlite3.OperationalError: near "AND": syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure that's proper sqlite syntax?

Comment: It's your answer so are YOU sure that's a proper sqlite syntax?

Comment: I just corrected the python syntax, the rest is on you